# drupal_set_breadcrumb() function doesn't work on "Add content" pages!

Tags: 7, panels, breadcrumbs

I have written a custom block and put it inside the panel of "Add Content" page, but it can not change the breadcrumb. Actually the code in module includes drupal_set_breadcrumb() function, which doesn't work on “Add content” pages. My code is working on the others pages!

I need your help to change only the breadcrumb of each "Add content" page without using the available modules for drupal breadcrumb. Because I have written my code and the customization level is so high which can not be obtained with those modules.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just solved it! It's too easy! Using the below function in template.php file:

```
function mytheme_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $sep = ' &gt; ';
  if (count($variables['breadcrumb']) > 0) {
    return implode($sep, $variables['breadcrumb']) . $sep;
  }
  else {
    return t("Home");
  }
}
```

and using the `arg()` values and `$variables['breadcrumb']` values in above function can enable you to check every pages path. Such as adding the below piece of code the above function:

```
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];

  $is_add_content=false;
  foreach($breadcrumb as $key=>$value){
    if(strpos($value,"node/add"))
      $is_add_content=true;
  }
```

References:

https://www.drupal.org/node/64067
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7